# Select userName from Table where userId = {1,2,3,4,...n}

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

is there any way to get the list of userName from a table where userId are many,

```
userId      userName
1              abc
2              xyz
3              pqr
```

please seaa below the query i wish to execute via `jdbcTemplate`,

```
String query = "Select userName from table_1 where userId = {1,2,3}";

HashMap<int,String> = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql);

 // HashMap - int : userId, String - userName
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use

```
select userName from Table where user_id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @Stelian Galimati I would say answers your question directly. However, if want to have more flexibility with your querys I would recommend looking up nested SQL selects. [This may be a helpful beginners tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm) for you. In addition, there is [this](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial) that will allow you to test out your SQL. A quick example of this would be:

```
SELECT userId
FROM table_1
WHERE userName IN {
    SELECT userName
    From table_2
    WHERE userLastName = "Smith"
}
```

To elaborate on @Stelian Galimatis answer, if you wanted to select any number of user_names given a number of parameters (which may be objects and not int values) you could additionally use named parameters as such,

```
SELECT userName
FROM table_1
WHERE userId IN {
    :user1,
    :user2,
    :user3,
}
```

Additional tutorials you may find more helpful to you at [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-select-query.htm).

Comment: Thanks Prancer for detail description.